# How to make a responsive mosaic css fullscreen width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, image-scaling

Hello am having troubles to make this responsive mosaic, what I am trying to acomplish here is to keep the same order of the 7 images and if the screen is smaller make the mosaic full width but with their respective proportions in a mobile screen but maintaining the order.

this is my css:

```
#mosaic {
              width: 100%;
              background-color: aqua;
            }
            .largeImg, .smallImg {
              /*display: inline-block;*/
              float: left;
            }
            .largeImg {
              /*width: 40%;*/
              background-color: #165384;
            }
            .smallImg {
              /*width: 60%;*/
              background-color: #EF0808;
            }

            .col-wrap {
              display: inline-block;
            }
```

this is my demo: [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gabouh075/g5ofv875/embedded/result/)

Hope someone can help and thanks for reading.

Comment: your link is incorrect! please do update the right one..

Comment: i apologize for the wrong link, already updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your desired functionality using `media queries`, the code below is specific for mobile devices, try it on;

```
@media all and (max-width: 658px) { // mobile devices
    #mosaic { 
        display:block; // to have each musaic in one line
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah media queries does help but am trying to have a div with a rectangle  shape and with the form of 1 image and the other 6 images smaller in 2 columns inside this rectangle shape and no matter what screen resolution if is mobile it should see the same rectangular grid, I know it disagree to some responsive guides but i need to keep the shape of a rectangle with 1 big image and 6 smaller

Comment: well, you can have it designed in anyway you like,  using media queries, check this link out; https://jsfiddle.net/Escape_Character/g5ofv875/3/